# Extjs name based UUID generation

Tags: javascript, extjs

Extjs doesn't support generation of name based UUID generation. 
Version supported for generating are version 1 and 4. 
Any Lib or code to import to generate version 3(name based).
Please help

Comment: Please, provide more details on what you are doing or what you want achieve with examples.

Comment: [this is uuid generation for random based](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript). Similar way need UUID to generate for NameBased RFC 4122. Using Extjs can generate Random Based but doesnot support for namebased.